# Python: How to separate the user's first and last name using str.partition

Tags: python

I'm still a beginner in using Python and I'm having a problem with creating function prompting the user to enter a name and then returning it to a tuple. But the main concern I am dealing with is that from that tuple, I must separate the first and last name and then assigning to separate variables using the specific method str.partition.

I have tried writing the following code below but still is a bit confused / quite seem to pinpoint what's wrong with my code.

```
def get_names():
    name = ("Please enter your name: ")
    get_names = name
    name.partition("")
    return name
```

Comment: you just need to ad a separator that is not an empty string. try using fName, lName = name.partition(" ") so it partitions on the space in between first an last name.

Comment: [Side note](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: `partition()` assumes there are 3 elements in the string you are trying to split. But it looks like your strings have only 2. Use `split()` instead. You *can* use `partition()` with a single space, but that will give unwanted results if your user types two spaces, and it is a bit unnatural to regard a space as a name element. `split()` will also work better if your user types a middle name.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```py
def get_names():
    name = input('Please enter your name: ') # prints its argument and waits for user input
    return name.split() # returns a list e.g. 'first last' -> ['first', 'last']

get_names() # call our function so that it runs
```

If you want to use `partition`, replace the return line with:

```
names = name.partition(' ') # our delimiter is the argument, a space character
return names[0], names[-1] # -1 is the last argument
```

Instead of `-1` you could use `2`, because the third argument will be everything that came after the first space character found. However, I'd use `split` for this reason:

```
>>> 'first middle last'.split()
['first', 'middle', 'last']
```

```
>>> 'first middle last'.partition(' ')
('first', ' ', 'middle last')
```